# Why does css transition occur upon revealing an element, but doesn't upon hiding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

Long story short - check the question title :)

I'm working on a nav for my project, and recently I've encountered a strange error. Here's a little background:

1. I want some custom animated hide/reveal behavior implemented, so simply using jQuery 1.10 `show()` and `hide()` methods won't suffice: I'm toggling a class on the element in question.
2. The class I toggle is called `.hidden`. It's used along with the class `.toReveal` to avoid having to set `overflow:hidden;` to each of the items I want revealed. I've also mentioned I'm going for animated hide/reveal behavior, so I'll provide the relevant CSS:

> ```
> *{-webkit-transition:0.3s all;-moz-transition:0.3s all;}
>
> .hidden, .hidden * {
>     padding-top:0 !important;
>     padding-bottom:0 !important;
>     margin-top:0 !important;
>     margin-bottom:0 !important;
>     height:0 !important;
>     border-top-width:0 !important;
>     border-bottom-width:0 !important;
> }
>
> .toReveal, .toReveal * { overflow:hidden; height:auto;  }
> ```

So the experience I get is rather strange: when I expand the hidden element - the transition is going as planned. But when I try to hide the element - the transition doesn't happen.

I've found little traces of what's actually causing the trouble: if I remove `height:0 !important;` line from the code - the transition does happen, but the element doesn't collapse, while collapsing is the whole point of this :)

Here's a jsFiddle to the simplified prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/KCAHe/

Steps to see the desired behavior:

1. Click on dev/local
2. Advanced button will appear: click on sandbox

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Click on dev/local Keep clicking on Advanced

Comment: Can you try this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/KCAHe/1/)? Is this what you want?

Comment: @Harry is it possible to make the input slide from top like 'Advanced' button? It looks like a solution, but I'd like to know HOW this thing works and WHAT is causing the trouble :)

Comment: It was the `overflow: hidden` that was causing the trouble. I have no idea why though. I will let you know once I find it. For the "slide from top", it seems to be working that way only. (Try checking after setting a bigger height)

Comment: That's super-weird, but it's `overflow:hidden` indeed. As for slide from top - `display:block` solves the problem, since `<input>` is inline by default. You could post a definitive answer and I'll accept it. Given the amount of time and effort I've put into this - it's worth a goddamn article in a mag >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Generally animating/transitioning from 0 to auto does not work. Changing the `height` from `auto` to some fixed value for the `.toReveal` CSS class will fix the issue.

```
.toReveal{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 30px; /* set height such that it is big enough to accomodate its contents.*/
} 
.toReveal * {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
}
```

**Note:** The transition part from `height: 0` to `height: auto` is already working for you by using Option 2. But you might want to have a look at this [**article**](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animating_height/) also.

---

**Option 2:** (used by OP based on feedback to comments)

Remove the `overflow: hidden` and it seems to fix the issue.

Also, as you have mentioned in the OP comment, adding `display: block` will make it slide from top because `<input>` is inline by default.

**Modified CSS**

```
.toReveal, .toReveal * {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/KCAHe/3/)

Alternatively, adding `overflow: visible !important;` to the `.hidden, .hidden *` CSS also seems to work.